# I need to draw shapes on a canvas using the coordinates from a txt document

Tags: python-3.x, canvas

I have a text file with the following in it

```
50 50
50 100
100 50
50 50
-1 -1
100 100
150 150
150 100
-1 -1
```

Code

```
from simplegraphics import *

def draw_shapes():
    file_name = input("What file do you want to read: ")
    file = open(file_name, 'r') #opening the file in read mode
    open_canvas(400, 400)
    lowest = -1
    highest = " "

    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip()
        x, y = line.split(" ")
        x = int(x) #converting the variable into ints
        y = int(y)
        draw_line(10,10,10,10)

    file.close() #closing the file    
    close_canvas_after_click()

draw_shapes()
```

I've split them and converted into ints, I just cant seem to get the last step of telling it to draw the shapes to the canvas